# How to #define in a macro (or alternatives)

Tags: c, macros

I have this code:

```
#ifdef something32                           <----- might not be defined
    the_real_value = thing[something32];
    thing[something32] = my_value;
#else
    the_real_value = thing[something];   <------- guarantied to be defined (something)
    thing[something] = my_value;
#endif

#ifdef THE_OTHER_THING                       <--------- might not be defined
#ifdef something32
    thing32[something32] = my_value;
#else
    thing32[something] = my_value;
#endif
#endif
```

and I'll be using that a lot of times so I'd like to replace it with a macro. I know #ifdef's can't live insde a macro so I'm wondering how else I could replace all that code. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that `something32` is just one of a pretty long list of variables.

The idea is to have something like

```
SHORTEN_MY_CODE(something, something32);
SHORTEN_MY_CODE(another_something, another_something32);
etc...
```

Comment: `#ifdefs` can't be in a macro, but a macro can be in an `#ifdef`.

Comment: @CarlNorum sorry for the confusion, I'll edit my question and you'll see why I can't use that.

Comment: I think there is a right way of doing what you are trying to do, but I would need to see the rest of your code to help.

Comment: @MarkLakata that's pretty much all of it. If it helps I can paste the real code. Do you want me to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your logic around and change what the macro is defined as based on condition - rather than defining a macro that contains a condition:

```
// define

#ifdef something32
    #define SOMETHING_VAR something32
#else
    #define SOMETHING_VAR something

#define SHORTEN_MY_CODE the_real_value = thing[SOMETHING_VAR]; \
    thing[SOMETHING_VAR] = my_value;

#ifdef THE_OTHER_THING
     #define SHORT_OTHER() thing32[SOMETHING_VAR] = my_value
#else
     #define SHORT_OTHER() 
#endif

// usage
SHORTEN_MY_CODE()
SHORT_OTHER()
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
#ifdef something32
    #define MY_MACRO the_real_value = thing[something32]; \
    thing[something32] = my_value; 
#else
    #define MY_MACRO the_real_value = thing[something]; \
    thing[something] = my_value;
#endif
```

Comment: @alexandernst does it have to use a #ifdef or could you use ternary. A compiler will optimize out branches that never happen in this case

Comment: No, I can't as ```something32``` might not be defined. Anyways, ```something``` is guarantied to be defined.

Comment: @alexandernst best I can think of right now - it is still reduced

Comment: Thank you for the update, anyways, this is still missing the ```THE_OTHER_THING``` case which will always happen, just after the ifdef/else.

Comment: The last - 1 edit was ok, the last one has a bug/no-no, that is: something32 is just one variable from a list of at least 20, so I can't #ifdef it. A part from that, the last - 1 edit is what I'll probably use :)

Comment: @alexandernst if its a variable then what is #ifdef checking - is a #define constantly changing?

Comment: The thing is that something is defined with around another 20 variables, and I need to write that ```SHORTEN_CODE``` for each one. So I can't #ifdef every single variable that is defined as this defeats the whole purpose of my question :p

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing C++, I would consider just writing a function and declare it inline. If you have a full function, then you can put #ifdef inside the function.

If you post more of your code, I think we can offer more help. Misuse of the c-preprocessor is rampant. You probably don't want to use it the way you propose.

I don't understand how `something`,`something32` and `OTHER_THING` get defined. Are they defined at the project level, or inside some header file?

---

Update: suggestion. However, you may want to read this first : [access to the sys_call_table in kernel 2.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840324/access-to-the-sys-call-table-in-kernel-2-6)

```
void* Hook(int f, void* hooked) {
#ifdef CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION
    void *old = ia32_sys_call_table[f];
    ia32_sys_call_table[f] = hooked;
#else
    void *old = sys_call_table[f];
    sys_call_table[f] = hooked;
#endif
    return old;
}


...

Hook(__NR_read, hooked_sys_read);
Hook(__NR_write, hooked_sys_write);
```

Comment: I'm using C/C++, so that would be an option. ```OTHER_THING``` is ```CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION``` (Linux Kernel), while ```something``` and ```something32``` are ```__NR_read``` and ```__NR_read32``` (sys_calls). ```__NR_read``` will always exists, no matter what's the architecture, but ```__NR_read32``` will exist only on x64 AND IA32 emulation activated. Also, please keep in mind that this is not the only sys_call (there are a lot more).

Comment: Still need more sample code... You're obviously playing with fire if you are using library symbols such as `__NR_read` as offsets into some array. If you are writing assembly code in C, you are using the wrong tool....

Comment: Ok, here's the actual code: https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/blob/master/syshijack.h and https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/blob/master/hookfns.c